# Что за метод шифрования?

Tags: шифрование

Как дешифровать это?
Пример нескольких строчек:

```
656d 626c 792d 4353 6861 7270 2c20 5665
7273 696f 6e3d 302e 302e 302e 302c 2043
756c 7475 7265 3d6e 6575 7472 616c 2c20
5075 626c 6963 4b65 7954 6f6b 656e 3d6e
```

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что это какой-то шифр?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что нет.

Comment: Мюллер перехватил шифровку Юстаса.

Comment: `302e 302e 302e 302c` -> `0.0.0.0,`

Answer (score 6):

Это обычный текст в HEX.
Перевод: embly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=n
http://crypt-online.ru/crypts/text2hex/

Comment: Я попробовал все строчки так,в итоге превращается в какую-то дичь с квадратиками

Comment: Формат:XX WIN-1251 -> Декодировать

Comment: Так и делаю,если все строчки,то дичь какая-то

Comment: Ну ладно,спасибо

Comment: То, что указано в начале декодируется в "embly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=n"

Answer (score 5):

Это не шифрование, просто строка в hex-формате:

```js
var str = "656d 626c 792d 4353 6861 7270 2c20 5665 7273 696f 6e3d 302e 302e 302e 302c 2043 756c 7475 7265 3d6e 6575 7472 616c 2c20 5075 626c 6963 4b65 7954 6f6b 656e 3d6e"
    .replace(/\s/g, '')
    .match(/\w{2}/g)
    .map(x => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(x, 16)))
    .reduce((x, y) => x + y);
console.log(str)
```